# Uncaught TypeError after using button

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, browser

```
// ... created frameUp, frameDown, frameRight, frameLeft using createElement("DIV")

const button = document.getElementById("button")
button.addEventListener("click", addBorder); <---- error occurs on this line

// draws the top, bottom, right, left edges of the border
function addBorder() {
    document.body.appendChild(frameUp);
    document.body.appendChild(frameDown);
    document.body.appendChild(frameRight);
    document.body.appendChild(frameLeft);
}
```

border.js^

```
 ...
    <button id="button">Click me to add border!</button>
    <script src="border.js"></script>
...
```

taken from HTML^

I am trying to make a border around the chrome screen using a chrome extension, which works fine if I don't try to incorporate a button. When I change it to incorporate a button event listener, it is telling me that it cannot read properties of Null. My goal is to press the button->the border appears on screen.

[image]

My goal is: press the button --> the border appears on screen.

Without the button, it works fine: drawing a border upon the extension booting up.

With the button, it throws an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

I read numerous other posts but none of their solutions helped me solve the problem. I checked that the button id name was correct, rearranged the order of my code, etc.

Also, if I wrap the whole javascript code within a:

```
addEventListener("DOMcontentLoaded", function ()) {
```

It draws a border around the extension popup window instead of the browser, which is not what I want.

Comment: did you try creating the button in javascript using `document.createElement()`?

Comment: @Harshit T You're a genius! That worked! But now I'm struggling to leave the button in the chrome extension pop up but still make the border outside.

Comment: Sounds like you incorrectly load the same script in two places: in popup html and in `content_scripts` (or in executeScript). Each place should have its own script.